# Print a line of log file continuosly in current buffer

Tags: vim

How to print only one line of my log file (that is showing the log progress) continuously in present buffer? I could not find tail -f working for me.

Basically, I have made my own command using function call in .vimrc and later on I have opened the quickfix window to show the compilation errors. Presently, i am just echoing the message "running software in background" which seems static and the user may think that the system is hanged if he runs a large design. How can I show my progress simultaneously in the current buffer from the log file which ius updated continuously?

Comment: Have you tried filtering the external command? i.e. `!tail -f filename`. Doing just `tail -f filename`  won't work because `tail` is not a Vim command.

Comment: yes i did but there is i think it is not working because i am using that command after my execute command of running my software.   Is it any other way apart from reading a log file. Can i just read the outputs of currently executing command in my present buffer. that will also continuously display the message about execution of command continuously.

Comment: I cannot fully understand the question. In the title you've mentioned: "*Print a line of log file continuously in current buffer*". You can accomplish this with the following command: `yes $(sed -n '7,7p' filename)` assuming you want to print the 7th line of the file.

Comment: There is some issue in my log file. So, I was thinking to print the output of the command that i have made in vimrc file continuosly in current buffer so that the user can easily come to know about the progress of execution of the command in same buffer.